# How to merge 2 different scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this to position my div:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $(window).resize(function (){
        $('.classname').css({
            position:'absolute',
            left: ($(window).width() - $('.classname').outerWidth())/2,
        });
    });
    $(window).resize();

});
```

but after scrolling down, i want to stick on the top, so withouth positioning I use this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() > 150){
$('.class name').addClass('shrink');
        }
else{
    $('.class name').removeClass('shrink');
}
});
```

here is the css for shrink:

```
.shrink{
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Can someone help me, how to merge the two scripts?

thanks

Comment: Please provide working code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: When you say "merge", do you mean you don't want your resize and scroll handlers to clash trying to set different values for the same CSS properties?
 Wouldn't adding `.classname { position: absolute }` to your CSS and removing `position: absolute` from your resize handler do it?

Comment: Have you ever thought about using `position: sticky` ?..  It's pretty well supported nowadays, and seem to do what your after.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if i understand you correctly, but you can try this:

### CSS

```
.classname{
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.classname.shrink{
    left: 0 !important;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(window).resize(function (){
        $('.classname').css({
            left: ($(window).width() - $('.classname').outerWidth())/2,
        });
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 150){
            $('.classname').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else{
           $('.classname').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    });

    $(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but it doesnt really works. So I would like something like this: http://washingtonrowing.com/ <--- the blue navbar on this site. Thanks